# How to have the click event of a ListView item turn on and off the checkbox in the item template for the listview

Tags: listview, checkbox, user-controls, uwp

I have UWP app with a XAML listview in a user control as seen below.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvDevices"
          Margin="12,8,0,0"
          Grid.Row="4"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DeviceTemplate}"
          Width="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="lvDevices_ItemClick"
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/DevicesVMSampleData.xaml}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

The listview's item template is as follows.  You can see the item template has a check box and it is bound to my view model using two way binding.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DeviceTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelected" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="32" Grid.Column="0" Checked="chkSelected_Changed" Unchecked="chkSelected_Changed" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Tag="{Binding ID}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="500"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="User:" Margin="0,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding User}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="btnInfo" Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Image x:Name="imgInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Assets/InfoIcon-100.png" Height="50" Width="50" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The listview's datacontext is set to my view model.

```
ucDeviceInfo.DataContext = iobj_DevicesViewModel;
```

So what I want is when the user clicks on anitem in the listview, the checkbox for that item updated with a check mark or have its check mark removed.  I figured the best way to do that would be to set the 'Selected' property in the ViewModel to true or false when the user clicks on the row then notify the view that the property has changed.  (The list of items is an observable collection.).

I try to accomplish this in the following manner:

In the UserControl - when the user clicks on a row I call a method back in the base page using this code:

```
private void lvDevices_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        StartPage lobj_ParentForm;         

        lobj_ParentForm = ((StartPage)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content);
        lobj_ParentForm.SendNotifyPropertyChanged( ((Device)e.ClickedItem).ID);
    }
```

In the base page I call a method in my ViewModel using this code:

```
public void SendNotifyPropertyChanged(int pi_DeviceID)
    {
        iobj_DevicesViewModel.DeviceSelectedInListView(pi_DeviceID);
    }
```

Then in the view model I update the selected property for the device and call the notify property changed function using this code:

```
public void DeviceSelectedInListView(int pi_DeviceID)
    {
        Device lobj_SelectedDevice;

        lobj_SelectedDevice = (from lobj_Device in Devices
                       where lobj_Device.ID == pi_DeviceID
                       select lobj_Device).ToList<Device>()[0];


        lobj_SelectedDevice.Selected = !lobj_SelectedDevice.Selected;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Devices");
        SelectionsChanged();
    }

    public void SelectionsChanged()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDeviceCount");
    }
```

The challenge is that when I do this and call the notify property changed method, the checkbox of the item in the listview I just clicked on is not updated.  Any idea how I can get the checkbox to update correctly when a user clicks on a row in the listview?

Link to sample project that illustrates this issue is
[Example Code](https://github.com/gceaser/ListViewWithCheckBox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your code - you have almost done it right. Your collection reference `Devices` doesn't change so binding won't update the whole collection, also you don't add/remove element, so ObservableCollection could have updated. In this case you need to call property changed on item's class. To do it just implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* at Device class:

```cs
public class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set { selected = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(Selected)); }
    }
    // rest of the class
```

After this you also don't need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Devices");` every time something change inside the item, the binding will do the job. As you have *ObservableCollection* I don't think you will have to call it at all.

[The modified sample you have shared](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=87995A9E6AADB641!52834&authkey=!AKyww70ABqZv0K8&ithint=file%2czip).

---

I'm not quite sure why you don't use the default ListView's checkboxes. If you set the selection mode to *Multiple* then you will see a checkbox at every item. If you want to handle some more actions you can subscribe to *SelectionChanged* event. A sample ListView with standard checkboxes:

```xml
<ListView Name="myList" SelectionChanged="myList_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="First item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Second item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Third item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Fifth item"/>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

In your code it's hard for me to say what is wrong as I cannot see your item class, I don't know if you have property *Selected*, does it implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* and more minor things.

Comment: I can't use the listview's checkbox items because even when there is no text associated with them there is a huge space gap after the checkbox which I cannot seem to get rid of.  Also - how would I be able to bind the property of that check box to my ViewModel?

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr As for the margin - have you tried to modify item's style? Also each item has *IsSelected* property which you can probably use. Of course it's possible to do it manually like your idea, but it's hard to say what is wrong without seeing more code - can you share a sampe project with the problem?

Comment: Added sample project.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr I've taken a look at your project, seems like you have declared binding in template, but forgot about property changed. I've made little edit in the answer.

Comment: If you look at my example code - I am calling notify property changed on the Observable collection which should notify the view that data in the collection has changed and should be updated.  Selected is a property of the objects stored in the observable collection.  Calling   

    NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected"); 

Immediately after the line of code

      NotifyPropertyChanged("Devices");

had no impact the list was still not corrected.  I am using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr I'm not quite sure now why raising property 'Devices' doesn't work, it may be some kind of optymalization, hence in fact your whole collection doesn't change (no new/removed elements). Nevertheless it's a bad pattern to reload whole collection when one of items changes itself. I've worked on your example code and if I'm right, I've made it to work - [see modified sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=87995A9E6AADB641!52834&authkey=!AKyww70ABqZv0K8&ithint=file%2czip).

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr I still haven't found the answer why it's not working when raising collection name, maybe it's optimization problem. I've simplified the problem and asked [separate question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33603919/2681948).

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr Now I hope it will work in your case.

Comment: So it does appear to work.  I did not think adding the notify property changes on Model was necessary in the past.  I wonder if that is something new.  Anyway it seems to work now.  Thanks