# Updating ListView's ItemsSource via INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

While answering [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33553691/2681948) I've stepped into one thing I try to understand. I've a *ListView*, which *ItemsSource* is bound to a property of my page. The page implements *INotifyPropertyChanged*, the *DataContext* is set, evrything works, I can see my list rendered on the screen. But if I change something inside one of the elements and raise property changed on the whole collection, the change is not visible on the screen, the getter is called, so the binding works, but nothing changes.

Why is it so? Is there any internal *ListView's* optmization going on?

The XAML code:

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" Height="400">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Modify item" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyItem(string name) { this.Name = name; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    private List<MyItem> elements = new List<MyItem> { new MyItem("Standard"), new MyItem("Standard"), new MyItem("Standard") };
    public List<MyItem> Elements { get { Debug.WriteLine("Collection getter"); return elements; } }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        elements[1].Name = "Modified one";
        RaiseProperty(nameof(Elements));
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I know how to make it work by implementing *InotifyPropertyChanged* in *MyItem* class. I also know that it's a bad pattern to reload whole collection when something changed inside one its item. I just want to ensure about some things.

---

**Other case** - it seems that binding makes a reference copy of source object, that's clear. But interesting is that when I bind to array of strings:

```cs
public string[] Elements { get; } = new string[] { "Standard", "Standard", "Standard" };

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Elements[1] = "Modified one";
    RaiseProperty(nameof(Elements));
}
```

Modification in XAML: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16"/>`.

Then calling `RaiseProperty(nameof(Elements));` updates the view, even without modifying the collection. So why binding works different way in this case? It seems that it simply returns array without checking for changes.

Comment: I woder what's wrong with the question so that it got downvoted. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the *getter* will be called because you are calling `RaiseProperty(nameof(Elements))`. But nothing will get updated because the property `Elements` is **unchanged**. It's still the exact same object. What's changed is its underlying object(`elements[1]`)'s property `Name`.

That's why in this case the `InotifyPropertyChanged` needs to be implemented at the `MyItem` level.

If you change your `Elements`'s type to `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`. Then when you add/remove items to/from it, the UI will get updated. But if the underlying `MyItem`'s property is changed like what you did above, the UI will still remain the same.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I've just [endured at reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/Binding.cs,2e068a13b9bdd228) and it seems that binding makes a weakreference of source object for future comparison. Seems that I got mislead when playing with List and Observable. But there is one more little thing - if I change elements to array `public string[] Elements { get; } = new string[] { "Standard", "Standard", "Standard" };` (change binding in template) and then modify `Elements[1] = "Modified one";` ...

Comment: ... then `RaiseProperty(nameof(Elements));` will update the view. It probably doesn't change the whole array reference, but this probably means that binding makes the exact copy of elements on stack? Then equals probably will return different collection as probably all valuetypes are checked.

Comment: I think that when you bind to values that are on *Stack* (not *Heap*), then binding doesn't check for changes. When you call `RaiseProperty(nameof(Elements));` event without changing elements, you will see that listview is refilled.

Comment: Interesting! I never tired that. BTW `List<string>` will not work.

Comment: Yes, that's because List<string> is a reference type. Though I've added in question another case, when bind to array of struct (which I think are value types) - in this case view is not being updated - what makes exception in my thinking.

Comment: But isn't `string[]` a reference type too?

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot abot that fact, that ruins my whole concept of this binding behavior.

Comment: I'm little lost with this, thus I've [posted a separate question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33608268/2681948).