# Different binding behavior for string[] and List<string>

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-10, uwp

I try to understand (without success) why binding behaves differentially when source object is `string[]` and `List<string>`. I have two lists, their only difference is *ItemsSource* - in one case *array* in second *List*:

XAML code:

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Modify items" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ArrayElements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="100" Margin="20"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListElements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="100" Margin="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public string[] ArrayElements { get; } = new string[] { "Standard", "Standard", "Standard" };
    public List<string> ListElements { get; } = new List<string> { "Standard", "Standard", "Standard" };

    public MainPage() { this.InitializeComponent(); this.DataContext = this; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayElements[1] = "Modified one";
        ListElements[1] = "Modified one";
        RaiseProperty(nameof(ArrayElements));
        RaiseProperty(nameof(ListElements));
    }
}
```

Once I click button, the first list (build upon array) gets refilled with new elements (seems like new *ItemsSource*), so I can see a little flicker and the change in second element.

The same time in the second list nothing changes - the reference to binding source doesn't change so we don't see the difference on screen (*PropertyChange* has no effect as no property has been changed) - that's clear.

So why the list where the *ItemsSource* is set to array behaves different?

[Sample to reproduce the issue](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=87995A9E6AADB641!52962&authkey=!ANto7n-A22DC4e0&ithint=file%2czip) (though almost whole code is above)

Comment: I can't reprodude this behaviour (in a WPF app). And of course I wouldn't expect any magic behind replacing an array element. The array instance doesn't change when you replace one of its elements, so a binding won't update, even if you fire the PropertyChanged event. What you actually need is a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged, e.g. ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Clemens That's what I thought - the array instance doesn't change. If it's not working the same in WPF, then I add a tag UWP, where it should be easy to reproduce.

Comment: Very interesting! Btw calling  RaiseProperty(nameof(ArrayElements)); is enough to trigger the refresh (=seeing the "little flicker"), you don't even need to change an item in the array.

Comment: @gregkalapos Yes that's right, it seems like array is assigned anew. The change in element is just to ensure the same behavior as with a *List*.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior in Silverlight either. Note not only `string[]` will notify underlying property changes, `object[]` will notify underlying `MyItem`'s `Name` change too. This is getting more interesting. :)

Comment: @JustinXL Good point - `object[]` makes it even more universal :)

Comment: I made some experimentation(used x:Bind,which also reproduces the issue and generates the binding code compile time which can be debugged). Conclusion: basically at the end the ItemSource property will be reset…and if you call ListView1.ItemsSource=ArrayElements and ListView2.ItemsSource=ListElements (ListView1 is the first one, 2 is the second one) then the one with the list is not refreshed, the other one is refreshed. So imho the answer is in the ItemsControl.ItemSource implementation. This is in the Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd file, but unfortunately marked with extern.

Answer (score -3):

It sounds weird to me but i never faced this Problem because i use ElementViewModel objects in an observable collection. Instead of changing the list-item / Array element i Change a property of the ElementViewModel and use the INotifyProperty Change there. It's not the actuall answer to you question but you can work around with this.

Comment: I'm not looking for the answer how to make it work, I want to know the difference in this behavior. I've already worked around this problem and haven't found the answer, thus I've posted this question.

Comment: okok i didnt know . thought least have a way to get it run then. actually as others could not reproduce maybe you are using a Framework Version with a bug and need to update? Because actually the NotifyCollectionChange you're doing should refresh the whole value = the whole list including all elements... An observable collection should not be necessary here - except for optimization if you have lots of entries.